# Syncfusion Datatabe Grid Bind: Grid is Null in Code Behind

Tags: webforms, grid, syncfusion

Im currently trying to do a basic bind on a list of objects. In the code behind, the reference to the Grid object is null.
Using this as a reference:
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet/grid/data-binding#datatable

.Net Version: 4.6
Syncfusion reference for grid: Syncfusion.Javascript.Web.Grid

In the designer it is defined as:

```
Syncfusion.Javascript.Grid<myEntity> gv;
```

On the aspx page:

```
<ej:Grid Id="gv" runat="server" />
```

And in the code behind on the page load function:

```
var myList = new List<myEntity>(){new myEntity()};
gv.GridModel.DataSource = myList;
```

But while debugging it shows that gv is null. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your query you are facing an issue while binding dataSource to Grid. The reported issue occur because the Grid instance is initialized wrongly in the designer page and also dataSource is wrongly bounded to Grid. Kindly modify your sample as below code example

GridFeatures.aspx.designer.cs

```
namespace SyncfusionASPNETApplication18  
{ 
   public partial class GridFeatures  
    { 
            protected global::Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web.Grid gv;     
    } 
}
```

GridFeatures.aspx

```
<ej:Grid ID="gv" runat="server"/>
```

GridFeatures.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            BindDataSource(); 
        } 
        private void BindDataSource() 
        { 
int code = 10000; 
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
            { 
                order.Add(new Orders(code + 1, "TOMSP", i + 0, 2.3 * i, "Münster", "Toms Spezialitäten", new DateTime(1991, 05, 15), new DateTime(1991, 05, 15), "Germany", "44087", false)); 

            .             .               .                 .               .             
            this.gv.DataSource = order; 
            this.gv.DataBind();           

        }
```

Comment: thank you, wrong type on the designer page was confusing me..thogh i do have one more question..it isn displaying and i believe its the order/what im importing for the javascript...any idea on the order or what packages i need for the grid?

Comment: Refer the following link to know about javascript Grid dependencies,

https://help.syncfusion.com/js/grid/getting-started